# Does setting session autocommit=0, inserting rows, commiting, allow for duplicate IDs if the procedure is called twice at the same time?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, transactions, spring-transactions, mysql-8.0

I have an API, which will call a MySQL 8 stored procedure. I've been reading up on transactions, and I've realised I don't really need the rollback/safety net of a transaction, but it does give a huge boost to inserting speed, so I wanted to do what's in the title. Set the session autocommit to false, insert stuff, commit, and set the auto commit to true again. The rows I'm inserting have auto incremented IDs.

1. Will this act as a defaut transaction, and block other insertions to the table IF another api request calls this same procedure, but with different data?
2. If the procedure is called twice, at the same time with different data, is there a risk of it auto generating the same row IDs?
3. I'm using Spring Boot. Is it possible to set the session auto commit to false there, do a bulk insert, commit, and set auto commit = 1 again? Which is better, the procedure way or bulkInsert?
4. Same question as in #1, but with bulkInsert in SpringBoot, no procedures called.

Comment: what do you use exactly spring-jdbc? You can set autocommit to false in different levels like  for data source or per connection. If you set it in connection level it will work as you expect i.e. will not effect any other ongoing execution as it will use a different connection. Yet if you give us some additional information regarding your actual inserting task there could be some other tricks to improve them like batch insert etc.

Comment: spring-jdbc yeah. I read up a bit more about it and did what I said in the other question, wrap the insert in a manual transaction and do another function call outside of it. Still not sure if getting the pool connection is more expensive than just calling a procedure that does it all though.

Comment: Well I have done similar high volume insertions (100M+) before. And batch insert would definitely help. In your case one of the issues could be the auto incremented id as they may cause some lock wait time depending on the engine. I remember that one time we used client generated uuid as id plus batch inserts and it was quite fast.

Comment: 100M is crazy. I'm on InnoDB. I've inserted 400 rows and it takes about 100ms, which is pretty damn high, no idea why. I've only 1 index, and the table has 5/6 columns. All within a transaction

Comment: I remember that we wrote our sqls by ourselves in our case because mysql jdbc driver somehow was not supporting batch operation. As it was 5 years back I don't know current status of it. But I found this which may help you http://java-persistence-performance.blogspot.com/2013/05/batch-writing-and-dynamic-vs.html

Comment: Appreciate it man! That link made me google quite a bit of stuff, and adding some hikari configs (and especially rewriteBatchedStatements=true) made inserts a TON faster. Thanks!

Comment: That would be really useful for the future if you share what you learned and experienced as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the main page that sped up my queries:
https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/MySQL-Configuration

And check what each option does on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html

The rewriteBatchedStatements=true sped up my bulkInserts by about 350%